# Почему sizeof возвращает не то значение?

Tags: c++

Есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class str{
public:
    str(const char* ttext){
        size = sizeof(ttext);
        text = new char[size];
        text = (char*)ttext;
    }

    char* text;
    int size;

    char operator[](int i){
        if(i<size){
            return text[i];
        }
        else{
            cout<<"123123"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    str* s = new str("Hello");
    cout<<s->text[5]<<endl;
    cout<<s->size<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Итак, почему sizeof возвращает 8, ведь символов всего 5. Даже если принять в расчет нулевой символ, будет 6 но никак не 8. Почему sizeof выводит не то?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это размер указателя, а не массива. Вот дискуссия по этому поводу: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/39447/

Comment: Да, как всегда затупил.

Comment: как я понял решение передавать размер массива в функцию? и еще есть вопрос правильней же возвращать ссылку на символл а не копировать его. Я правильно думаю? Как это сделать? Нашел решение только одно использовать исключения для обработки ошибок выхода за пределы массива, а для поддержки разных типов шаблоны.

Comment: C-style предполагает первый вариант. В C++ принято использовать std::string, std::vector и проч., т.е. стандартные контейнеры

Answer (score 1):

А что вам мешает использовать функцию strlen из `<`string.h> или `<`cstring>?
Вместо size = sizeof(ttext) пишем size = strlen(ttext) и получаем в size размер строки из ttext.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` это оператор языка он возращает размер объекта в байтах который ему передан. В вашем случае под "объектом" понимается указатель на строку, а не сама строка.

Чтобы получить размер именно строки можно использовать функцию из стандартной библиотеки [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) вот она понимает что указатель который ей передан это указатель массив символов с нулем в конце и будет считать количество символов в этом массиве.